# Will iron(III) sodium EDTA release its nitrogen into a water medium and become bioavailable to aquatic plants?

Tags: water, amines, chemical-biology

I am wanting to create an N-free [Hoagland's solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoagland_solution) and have discovered a recipe that includes sodium ferric ethylenediaminetetraacetate salt $(\ce{C10H12FeN2NaO8}).$ Will the nitrogen in EDTA release into the water and become bioavailable to aquatic plants?

Comment: In what form would you consider the nitrogen to be available to plants - nitrates, nitrites, free ammonia, glycine?

Comment: I will be measuring both nitrate and nitrite in the water, so those, I guess.

Comment: Then I think you are in the clear. There seems little chance that the nitrogens from EDTA will end up as nitrates or nitrites - see the reference in my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

This [paper](https://journals.asm.org/doi/pdf/10.1128/am.29.6.787-794.1975) which discusses microbial degradation of EDTA is the most relevant I could find. It identifies the major products of degradation:

> Included among these compounds were both isomers of ethylene-diaminediacetic acid (NN-EDDA, and NN'-EDDA), EDMA, NTA (nitrilotriacetic acid), and glycine.

No mention is made of nitrates, nitrites or free ammonia if those are the forms of nitrogen you are principally concerned about.